# GitHub API, getting 'Bad Credentials' when trying to request user data

Tags: reactjs, node.js, github

I'm trying to access the userData for a github user that logs into this website which is a react app using OAuth, and am facing a bad credentials error. I have the accessToken saved in local storage and have made sure that is correct before calling my getUserData() function.

Here's my code:

```js
// Server Side Code
// Get user data
// Access token is passed in as Authorization header
app.get('/getUserData', async function (req, res) {
    req.get('Authorization'); // BEARER ACCESS_TOKEN
    await fetch("https://api.github.com/user", {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': req.get('Authorization')
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    }).then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        res.json(data);
    });
});
```

```js
    // Client Side Code
    // Getting user data
    async function getUserData() {
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('accessToken'));
        await fetch("http://localhost:4000/getUserData", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('accessToken') // Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        }).then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            setUserData(data);
        });
    }
```

I've tried looking at the API docs, and am a little confused on how this all works. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the scopes of your access token to get github user data.
You can set it in your github settings page.

https://github.com/settings/tokens

Scope name to set: user/read:user